# Zxing which jar do I use, and why can't it start the activity?

Tags: android, zxing

I was trying to update an app I had done a while ago for a school project, when which I used zing for scanning barcodes. Since there appears to be a an android integration jar now, rather than just the core, when I first created the app. I added the android-integration-3.0.0.jar. I imported com.google.zxing.* in the activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.zxing.*;

import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, HttpCallback{
```

and I started the scan activity as such:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.getId() == R.id.scanButt){
            Intent in = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            in.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(in, 0);
        }
        if(v.getId() == R.id.viewButt){
            Intent in = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting this error however when I start the activity:

```
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834): Process: com.example.vinscanner, PID: 834
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN (has extras) }
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at com.example.vinscanner.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:218)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-04 23:35:02.708: E/AndroidRuntime(834):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 23:40:02.848: I/Process(834): Sending signal. PID: 834 SIG: 9
```

I then tried using the core-3.0.0.jar and even the core-2.1.0.jar which i used in the original, I got the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You add the `android-integration` JAR, which is correct. But you are not calling it in your code! Look at the javadoc for `IntentIntegrator`. It handles exactly the code you are trying to write here.

It also handles the case where the app is not installed, which is what the second error is. You need something installed, like Barcode Scanner, that responds to this `Intent`.